# Why is there tar leaking into my attic?

Tags: roof, attic

I was doing my own home inspection today to keep up on maintenance, and I found something pretty unusual in the attic.  On one of the boards in the roof a tar-like substance is leaking through the board.  It doesn't look to be wet or getting a lot worse, but what is this?  Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the sap is coming out of a board from the heat of the attic.

Comment: I just noticed this on the underside of all the 1x boards of my roof decking yesterday, and was about to ask this question myself! It is a totally normal thing, or indicative of a problem?

Comment: Pine is good for doing this. I would say it is normal, but it does not happen in all attics, nor on all boards.  Some boards have an over abundance of sap. Under normal temps you will only see this happen with Douglas fir, but it only has "pockets" that sap usually collects in. When the wood is subjected to high temps, then you will see what you have in the pictures above. In D fir it will show up as teensy beads all over the surface, at least in my experiences.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I have. A zillion tiny orange crystalline beads.

Comment: It's sap.  Not a concern.

Comment: Sure looks a pitch pocket to me too.

Comment: Sap. Seen it a lot in Florida